# SQL Indexed View - check I'm doing this correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an indexed (or persisted) view for part of a stored procedure. My hope is that it will reduce the execution time as the web app is timing out for some queries. The timeout is being caused by the relevant data having to be joined and where'd across a lot of very distinct rows and indexing some of the source tables has only done so much.

Anyway. Please excuse if some of the syntax isn't exactly correct, I have to do this from memory and I just want to give the idea. My view currently looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW myView WITH SCHEMABINDING
SELECT K1, K2, S1, S2, S3, S4 
FROM...
```

The original query uses S1-S4 in its SELECT statement and K1 and K2 as joining fields. Specifically the original query is something like:

```
SELECT tX.S1, tX.S2, tX.S3, tX.S4, t1.S5, t1.S6
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN anotherTable t2 ON t1.key=t2.key
INNER JOIN yetAnotherTable t3 ON t1.key=t3.key
INNER JOIN [various other tables which reference tX that I am putting into the persisted view]
```

My intention is to alter this with the view to be:

```
SELECT view.S1, view.S2, view.S3, view.S4, t1.S5, t1.S6
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN anotherTable t2 ON t1.key=t2.key
INNER JOIN myView v1 ON t1.key=view.k1 AND t1.key = view.k2
```

I am leaving the left join in place, partly as I am unsure how I could build that into the persisted view, but there isn't a great cost to this join in any case.

So my questions.

1. Am I correctly using a persisted view for this? Essentially, am I doing it right?
2. Will SQL Server calculate the indexes I need for this view, or will I need to do this myself?
3. If I need to create my own indexes, should I create separate indexes on k1 and k2, each with their respective S columns?

For example.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
ON view.k1
INCLUDE (S1, S3)
```

Or is it OK to just whack it all in one?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
ON view.k1, view.k2
INCLUDE (S1, S2, S3, S4)
```

Any other pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a handy guide on indexing views from the Microsoft Developer Network: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191432.aspx.